How do I remove a broken kernel image package that has a dependancy on a non existent packages?
I can no longer perform any updates or upgrades as I am getting the following error :
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-6.5.0-26-generic (--remove)
When I attempt to install or remove any package including linux-image-6.5.0-26-generic.
Not sure how to clear this problem.
$ uname -a
Linux WZ-M18xR2 6.8.0-45-generic #45-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Aug 30 12:02:04 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
Release:    24.04
Codename:   noble

Full error:
/etc/grub.d/bin/grubcfg_proxy: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-6.5.0-26-generic (--remove):
 installed linux-image-6.5.0-26-generic package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-6.5.0-26-generic
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

I have no idea what libcrypto is as is doesn't appear in any package search.

find /etc/grub.d/ -iname '*proxy*'  please.

The output from that is:
/etc/grub.d/10_linux_proxy
/etc/grub.d/bin/grubcfg_proxy

This question is similar to: Upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04 causes libcrypto errors, apt/dpkg broken. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The reason the remove is failing is because libcrypto is missing.... see above comment.
